# list.append of an instance of a class function

Tags: python, list, function, class, append

Initialized value of the list ac_hist.  Purpose to keep a historical track of position
    ac_hist = [[450,600]]

This code:

```
ac_hist.append(aircraft_list[i].get_position())
```

should result in a list of lists which represent different [x,y] position.  The value of get_position changes each time it is called. But the results are all the same.  It seems that I'm appending an instance of variable rather than a value and each time the value of the variable changes all of the appended items change value (except the value used to initialize the list)?

```
print ac_hist
```

yields the following:

```
[[450, 600], [1.414, 234.156]]
[[450, 600], [1.358, 234.552], [1.358, 234.552]]
[[450, 600], [1.302, 234.948], [1.302, 234.948], [1.302, 234.948]]
[[450, 600], [1.246, 235.344], [1.246, 235.344], [1.246, 235.344], [1.246,     235.344]]
```

Comment: You haven't even shown us that you're performing this `append()` more than once. How is anyone supposed to tell you what your code is doing if you don't show it to us? Please edit your question into an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You are appending copies of the same position list to your `ac_hist` list.  But it's impossible to give further advice without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  The append was inside of a for loop.  I was able to solve the problem by using a new list().  In this case list(temp).

```
for i in range(5):
    list(temp) = aircraft_list[i].get_position() 
    ac_hist.append(temp)
```

Because the result of aircraft_list[i].get-position was a 2 element list, I was appending the same list to ac_hist.  So each time I updated the value of the two element list, all of the elements of ac_hist took on the same value.

Thanks for the assistance.